# How to find the even numbers of a list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

The method below is used to display all the elements within a list. What would I need to do for it to show only the even numbers? I know I need to use something like (m%2==0), but I don't know exactly how to implement it.

```
public void all(MyList<Integer> m){
    
    int scenario = 0; 
    
    //Scenario 1. MyList is empty
    if (m.length() == 0) 
        scenario = 1;
    //Scenario 2. MyList is not empty
    else
        scenario = 2;

    switch(scenario){   
            
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("Empty MyList");
        break;
        
    case 2: 
        int size = m.length();
        System.out.println("MyList Contains the following " + size + " items: ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.println("Item " + i + ": " + m.getElement(i));
        
        break;

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Use modulo or remainder operator in Java

Comment: Inside the for loop, you can implement it with **If** statement

Comment: public static void checkEven(int number) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(number + " is even");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is not even");
    }
}